# Php Ajax json неправильно срабатывает условие file_exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Загружается новость с определенным названием html файла, если файл с таким названием существует выходит одно сообщение, если же нет то выходит другое. Но почему-то когда добавляешь новость с новым названием выводит сначала success, а потом резко меняется на errorest, хотя не должен, он должен ведь меняться после повторного клика.

```
<?php
$result = [];

$title=$_POST['titles'];
$text=$_POST['txt'];
$html_name=$_POST['html_name'];
$filename = 'news/'.$html_name.'.html';//проверка на наличие ошибок
if (file_exists($filename)){
    $result['message3'] = 'errorest';
    exit(json_encode($result)); // Выходим и превращаем массив $result в json
}
else
{
$title  =   $_POST['titles'];
$text   =   $_POST['txt'];
$html_name  =   $_POST['html_name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO news (title,text,html_name,date) VALUES ('{$title}','{$text}','{$html_name}',NOW())";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$strOuthtm  =   'blablabla';

$f = fopen('news/'.$html_name.'.html', "w"); 
fwrite($f, $strOuthtm); 
fclose($f); 
$result['message1'] = 'success'; 
exit(json_encode($result));
}
?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
      type:'POST', // Тип запроса
      url: 'handler.php', // Скрипт обработчика
      data: formData, // Данные которые мы передаем
      cache:false, // В запросах POST отключено по умолчанию, но перестрахуемся
      contentType: false, // Тип кодирования данных мы задали в форме, это отключим
      processData: false, // Отключаем, так как передаем файл
      success:function(data){
       var res = JSON.parse(data); // Парсим json
            if (res.message2 =='errorfile') {
            $('#result').text(res.message2);
            $('#result').show();
            }
            if (res.message3 == 'errorest') {
            $('#result').text(res.message3);
            $('#result').show();
            }
            if (res.message1 == 'success') {
            $('#result').text(res.message1);
            $('#result').show();
            }
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="upload-image" class="message_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="10">Название статьи</td>
      <td><input class="titles" id="titles" type="text" name="titles" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10">Название ссылки(англ)</td>
      <td><input class="html_name" id="html_name" type="text" name="html_name" required></td>
    </tr>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="image">Image file:</label>
              <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
            </div>
     <tr>
      <td>Текст</td>
      <td>
<textarea id="editor1" name="txt" cols="100" rows="20"> </textarea></td>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1" );
 AjexFileManager.init({
 returnTo: "ckeditor",
 editor: ckeditor1
 });
 </script>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
                <button class="button-send button" type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form> 
  <br>
 <div id="result_form"></div>
          <div id="result">
          </div>
           <div id="result2">
          </div>
```

Comment: К делу скорее всего не относится, но создаёте пустой массив $result. Ключ  message3 вижу, message1 - тоже, а второго номера не вижу. Я бы вообще сделал один ключ message, которому в зависимости от условий присваивал разные значения.

Comment: Да, я его буду вводить дальнейшем, убрала тот код, ибо там все работает нормально. А вот здесь почему-то проблема с условием, хотя вроде как по логике никаких проблем не должно быть. Такое ощущение будто при нажатии отсылаются 2 запроса.

Comment: Покажите как у вас свёрстана форма и при каком событии срабатывает ajax?